# Cannot login Google Account in Next.js App using NextAuth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to add Google Login in my website using NextAuth.js

I have already set up the needed setting in the Google Cloud Console.

However, I still can't login my Google Account in my Next.js

*http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?error=OAuthCallback*
[image: Try Signing in with a different account]

The terminal prompts this error message:

```
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error invalid_client (The OAuth client was not found.) {
  error: OPError: invalid_client (The OAuth client was not found.)
      at processResponse (C:\e-commerce\ecommerce-admin\node_modules\openid-client\lib\helpers\process_response.js:38:13)
      at Client.grant (C:\e-commerce\ecommerce-admin\node_modules\openid-client\lib\client.js:1354:22)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async Client.callback (C:\e-commerce\ecommerce-admin\node_modules\openid-client\lib\client.js:493:24)
      at async oAuthCallback (C:\e-commerce\ecommerce-admin\node_modules\next-auth\core\lib\oauth\callback.js:109:16)
      at async Object.callback (C:\e-commerce\ecommerce-admin\node_modules\next-auth\core\routes\callback.js:52:11)
      at async AuthHandler (C:\e-commerce\ecommerce-admin\node_modules\next-auth\core\index.js:208:28)
      at async NextAuthApiHandler (C:\e-commerce\ecommerce-admin\node_modules\next-auth\next\index.js:22:19)
      at async NextAuth._args$ (C:\e-commerce\ecommerce-admin\node_modules\next-auth\next\index.js:108:14) {
    name: 'OAuthCallbackError',
    code: undefined
  },
  providerId: 'google',
  message: 'invalid_client (The OAuth client was not found.)'
}
```

My [...nextauth].js file contains this code:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET
    }),
  ]
})
```

My .env file only contains GOOGLE_ID and GOOGLE_SECRET.

Do I need to fix something in the Google Cloud Console? Or is there a problem/missing in my code?

p.s. sorry for the bad english since it is not my first language.

Comment: I haven't used next auth much so I could be wrong on this but i'm pretty sure that nextjs doesn't expose env variables to client that are not prefixed with NEXT_PUBLIC_, so you may need to change your env variables to be NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ID, NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_SECRET.

This would only be the case if NextAuth uses client processes for authentication which makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I uninstall and reinstall the 'next-auth' package, and then everything worked fine. I think next-auth experimental/beta v5 version needs to be configured differently, then its previous version, otherwise it will throw this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the version of the `openid-client` package, one of the `next-auth` dependency: reinstalling force to update it at 5.6.4 version that fix the invalid client issue.

PS: never prefix the Google Client Id and Secret with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` otherwise their values will be exposed client-side while they should be kept only on the server side!

Answer (score 0):

If you add middleware that blocks a page this error can happen.